# issue with jquery ajax cross domain xml response

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my code to access `xml` from a website

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/Ndfrt/search?conceptName=TESTOSTERONE",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser

      });
});

function xmlParser(xml) { 
    $(xml).find("entry").each(function () {
        $(".entirecont").append($(this).find('inputConceptName').text());
    });
}
```

it's working fine in local when i push this code to production it's giving me the cross domain restrictions.

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpBtC/96/)

I know it's a cross domain request but, how can i fix it??

Thanks

Comment: so you want some xml from corssdomain ajax. `jsonp` is the dataType for it.

Comment: but if i put jsonp how can i access i need xml

Comment: As I see, there is no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" header. If you want to get xml by crossdomain ajax, it have to be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With XML, your only real option for a true cross-domain request is if that server supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), allows your origin, and your browser supports it. (If they have a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) option, though, that would be easier. Sadly, though, a quick look at their API page suggested they only support XML and JSON, not JSONP. But look for yourself, don't take my word for it, I didn't do a detailed read. It's slightly odd if they support JSON but not JSONP, in my view.)

Another option I've sometimes heard discussed but have done is using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) as a [cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax).

Of course, you can also run your own server, make the requests to *it*, and have it query the rxnav.nlm.nih.gov feed and return it to you. Then the SOP doesn't come into it.

Side note: To use CORS with jQuery in IE8 or IE9, you need a plug-in that handles using the special `XDomainRequest` object (IE8 and IE9's `XMLHttpRequest` object doesn't do CORS). IE10 finally fixes that.

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth: Yes, but as I say, there's a patch or plug-in around somewhere that updates jQuery to handle doing that for you...

Comment: thnx crowder but let me check if there is any plugin doing that work

Comment: jquery doesn't support XDomainRequest??

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth: That's correct, jQuery doesn't support the Microsoft-specific `XDomainRequest` object. It supports cross-domain requests (to the extent it has to explicitly support them), but not via the `XDomainRequest` object. This is intentional (in my view, it's misguided -- rather like `XDomainRequest` itself -- but intentional). Microsoft have seen the error of their ways and added CORS support to `XMLHttpRequest` like everyone else did in IE10 and later, but for IE8 and IE9 there's this gap. Hence the plug-in or patch.

Comment: can u give me the URL for a patch or plugin

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth: I don't have it handy, but it shouldn't be hard to find in a search.

Comment: @Crowder does this plugin supports my need ??https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth: It claims it does. But do you know that the server supports CORS and allows your origin?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `CORS` or `JSONP` in a cross domain request. An AJAX request to fetch XML will not work cross domain

The workaround is to create a server-side proxy on your local server using PHP/ASP.Net/language of choice and call that via AJAX instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, I wasn't clear in the answer, I'll amend.

Comment: Not seeing why this is downvoted. I mean, yes, CORS requests are still Ajax request so there's a clarity thing, but I wouldn't downvote on that basis.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make cross domain request via ajax (expect json).

I suggest you make local ajax request, and on server side connect to cross domain server to get data which you need.

Comment: *"...expect json..."* Assuming you meant "except", you can't make cross-domain calls for JSON, either. You can do JSONP, which is a different but similar-looking thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flxhr from https://github.com/flensed/flXHR to run cross domain ajax call

Sample Code to use

```
function crossDomainCall(){
    var flproxy = new flensed.flXHR({
        autoUpdatePlayer: true,
        instanceId: "myproxy1",
        onerror: handleError,
        onreadystatechange: handleCrossDomainCall
    });
    flproxy.open("POST", url);
    flproxy.send(null);
}

function handleCrossDomainCall(XHRobj){
    if (XHRobj.readyState == 4) {
        var xmlDoc = XHRobj.responseXML;
        //
    }
}
```