# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource'

Tags: jquery

I am consuming Rest Services (GET/Post) using jQuery AJAX(Rest API)and getting issue related with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" when trying to hit the server for the Get/Post request.

my query is how i can fix the problem ... if I am not permissible to make any change at server side(which is providing services to consume, developed in Java).

I can make changes only from my jQuery side.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is on the server that you are sending the request to. It needs to return a header that ignores the HTTP access control.

See here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: hi, ... I know this already, but the scenario is.. i cannot make any change at server side. will it be possible to configure something from the client side so that it can work?

Comment: also.. is it a good thing to allow access for the other domains using 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * '... i believe i will be loosing security,because it will be a loop hole for my application?

Comment: To my knowledge it depends on what data you will get back. You mention that the API is REST, so I am assuming that you receive JSON. JSONP allows a page to receive JSON data from a different domain by adding a `<script>` element to the page which loads a JSON response with a callback from a different domain. If you are using jQuery you can add `dataType: 'jsonp'` to your AJAX call, that should help.

Comment: actually. I am using dataType:'xml'.

Comment: Well I actually don't know about XML, but stated here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560468/issue-with-jquery-ajax-cross-domain-xml-response - You should be able to use YQL, but again, I have no experience with this: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/